# Print reversely the elements of a list using recursion

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list

I want to print reversely the elements of a list using recursion, but I get an execution error !

Can someone help?

```
typedef struct node
{
    int val;
    struct node* next;
}node;
typedef struct list
{
    node* head;
}list;
void display(list L)
{
    if(L.head == NULL)    return;
    L.head= L.head->next;
    display(L);
    printf("%d\t",L.head->val);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using :

```
typedef struct list
{
    node* head;
}list;
```

you can simply pass the "node n" instead, and call it recursively using `n->next`, as follows:

```
void display(node *n){
    if(n != NULL){
       display(n->next);
       printf("%d\t",n->val);
    }
}
```

And then call that method from the outside as follows:

```
display(node->head);
```

or

```
display(node.head);
```

Depending on how you have allocated the structure "node".

**Side Note:**

I would actually renamed your structures to:

```
typedef struct List
{
    int val;
    struct List* next;
}List;
```

and then call:

```
void display(List *l){
    if(l != NULL){
       display(l->next);
       printf("%d\t",l->val);
    }
}
```

IMO it better expresses the use-case in hand.

A Full example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct List
{
    int val;
    struct List* next;
}List;

void display(List *l){
    if(l != NULL){
       display(l->next);
       printf("%d\t",l->val);
    }
}

List *addElement(List *l, int val){
      if(l == NULL){
         List *node = malloc(sizeof(List));
         node->val = val;
         node->next = NULL;
         return node;
      }
      else 
         l->next = addElement(l->next, val);
      return l;
}


void freeList(List *l){
    if(l != NULL){
      freeList(l->next);
      free(l);
    }
}

int main(){
   List *l = NULL;
   l = addElement(l, 1);
   l = addElement(l, 2);
   l = addElement(l, 3);
   l = addElement(l, 4);
   l = addElement(l, 5); 
   display(l);
   freeList(l);
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
5   4   3   2   1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void display(node *N){
    if(N != NULL){
       display(N->next);
       printf("%d\t",N->val);
    }
}
```

and in main:

```
int main (void)
{
    //...
    display (L.head);
```

Comment: And in main: `display(L.head);` or `display(L->head);` depending on `L` being declared locally as `list` or as `list *`. You shouldn't be able to use `node` hese as it is a type name. And even if you can, it's not wise to call a list a `node`.